# how to change language in Hippo cms

Tags: hippocms

I am new to Hippo CMS. I am using Hippos CMS 7.9.3 community addition.I am using eclipse as an IDE. I wanted to know when we login on HIPPO there are default languages coming up ,if I want to add any language in it and based on the language added I need to change all the pages and contents after login .Is there any way to do it? currently i am having options of english,french,dutch and netherlands at the time of login

Comment: Do you mean the language of the CMS itself (the dropdown at the login page) or the different languages of content inside the CMS?

Comment: yes,languages that are coming at the time of log in hippo cms and console and the content after we log in. Both places I need to add a language say for example Hindi

Answer (score 0):

The languages in the login page are build into the i18n of the CMS.

In case you want to add an additional language you should see the [Translate the CMS page](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/editor-interface/translate-the-cms.html) on from the documentation. This will add another language and the login page for the CMS and Console and will translate all labels found in the CMS. Because this will take some effort from your part it would be a shame if this would get lost. Therefor I would like to ask you to file a JIRA issue (like mentioned on that page) with your changes, so this can be added to the community edition of the CMS.

Now if you want to be able to add a translatable language to a document you will need to read the ["Add a translatable language documentation page"](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/translations/add-a-translatable-language.html).

Comment: thanks jeroen.(http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/editor-interface/translate-the-cms.html)Translate the CMS page depicts with intelliJ and not with eclipse.Also when I use ""Add a translatable language documentation page" link given by you it will only add an option of new created language in new translated folder. Can you please suggest how can I add new language in dropdown at login and after choosing new language all the labels should reflect accordingly

Comment: The first link http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/editor-interface/translate-the-cms.html is actually what you want to do (translate the labels in the entire CMS). The intelliJ part is only for opening the files, which you can with Eclipse as well, but just with another keyboard shortcut.

Comment: jeroen , there are 2 concerns.1) add new language in dropdown 2)Change all labels. Do you have any doc which can help me to do so with Eclipse as i have windows os and IntelliJ works only on linux system. The Link You shared only describes with IntelliJ and its shortcuts.I am not able to find those paths on eclipse

Comment: Yes both 1 and 2 are covered by that page. IntelliJ also works on Windows, but if you want to stick with Eclipse you can use Navigate -> Goto Resource (in Eclipse) as a replace ment of CMD + Shift + N in IntelliJ. Because there are quite some instructions and tools to help in this process written based on linux command line tools on that page, you might want to install Cygwin on your Windows laptop, because my windows command line skills are a bit rusty and perhaps better suited for a different question here on SO.